# Importing large csv file to sql server with python

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

I have pulled a csv file into python and need to insert it into sql server. I have successfully done it with a smaller file but the current one I am trying to import has over 600,000 rows. When I run the code with the larger file it will run for a few minutes and then I get the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

my code is as follows.

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://'+UID+':'+PWD+'@'+DATABASE)

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\username\file', chunksize=10000)
for i in data:   
    i.to_sql(u'table1', engine,if_exists='replace',index=False)

print "My program took", time.time() - start_time, "to run"
```

Comment: Try using `pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\greicher\file', chunksize=10000, encoding='utf8')`

Comment: If it's possible, try to make use of bulk insert. That's the fastest way to insert data into mssql.

Comment: I have added the encoding='utf8' and i have not gotten an error yet but it has been running for at least 30 minutes. I had previously tried bulk insert but i do not have permission

Comment: The encoding attribute answered your question, you might want to ask a new one for the performance issue.

Comment: Use `csv module` instead of `pandas` will improve performance and minimize memory footprint.